# Contour integration - evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x(x^2+1)} \ dx$ around a semi-circle

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, contour-integration

I am trying to show that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x(x^2+1)} \ dx=\pi(1-e^{-1}).$$

I considered a semi-circle in the upper-half plane, indented at the origin, orientated counter-clockwise with radius $R$ and $r$ of the outer and inner circular regions respectively ($r<1<R$).

[image]

> How do we determine the two straight line segments on the contour (from $-R$ to $-r$ and $r$ to $R$)?

For the segment from $-R$ to $-r$, I let $y(x)=-x,\ \ x\in [R,r]$, such that $$\int_{R}^{r} \frac{e^{-ix}}{x(x^2+1)} \ dx\implies\Im\left(\int_{R}^{r} \frac{e^{-ix}}{x(x^2+1)} \ dx\right)=\int_{r}^{R} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x^2+1)} \ dx.$$

Similarly for the segment from $r$ to $R$, I let $y(x)=x,\ \ x\in [r,R]$, such that $$\int_{r}^{R} \frac{e^{ix}}{x(x^2+1)} \ dx\implies\Im\left(\int_{r}^{R} \frac{e^{ix}}{x(x^2+1)} \ dx\right)=\int_{r}^{R} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x^2+1)} \ dx.$$

Hence the sum of the two contours is $$2\int_{r}^{R} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x^2+1)} \ dx.$$ But computing the remaining contours, this $2$ should be a $1$ for the result to follow.

But where is the error in my logic?

Comment: When you take $r\to 0$ and $R\to \infty$ $$ 2 \int_r^R \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x^2+1)}dx$$ becomes $$ 2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x^2+1)}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x^2+1)}dx.$$ Is it possible you've just made this small error?

Comment: Shit, I think it is that simple. Does this work iff the integrand is even (the integrand is odd in this case)?

Comment: The integrand is even

Comment: But it is the ratio of two odd functions (e.g. $21/7=3$). But then if we denote the integrand by $f(z)$, then $f(-z)=f(z)\implies$ it is even. I am confused...

Comment: The ratio of two odd functions is even. Same with the product of two odd functions. This has little to do with the product and ratio of odd numbers (and note that the ratio of two odd numbers doesn't even need to be an integer, although if it is, it will certainly be odd).

Comment: Yep I was just reading something similar on wikipedia. I didn't think my problem came down to something quite simple. Thanks a lot for the help. If you'd like to convert your initial comment into an answer, I would be happy to upvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when you take $r\to 0$ and $R\to \infty$ $$ 2 \int_r^R \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x^2+1)}dx$$ becomes $$ 2\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x^2+1)}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x(x^2+1)}dx$$ so you've just made a small mistake.

Answer (score 0):

By defining $F(a)$ as $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(a x)}{x(x^2+1)}\,dx$ you may notice that
$$\begin{eqnarray*} (\mathcal{L} F)(s) &=& \int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)e^{-as}}{x(1+x^2)}\,dx\,da\\ &\stackrel{\text{Fubini}}{=}&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(s^2+x^2)(1+x^2)}\stackrel{\text{PFD}}{=}\frac{\pi}{s(s+1)}\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence
$$ F(a) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{s(s+1)}\right)(a)=\pi(1-e^{-a}) $$
and you just need to set $a=1$ to find the value of the original integral.